# A dataset for Earth satellite size information?

Tags: artificial-satellite, satellite-constellation, skyfield

I am lookin for a dataset where I can find or calculate the size information of an Earth satellite as described in the seconds page of [this paper](https://www.space-track.org/documents/How_the_JSpOC_Calculates_Probability_of_Collision.pdf). It is basically the radius of the smallest sphere which surrounds a satellite. I haven't been able to find a single dataset that provides this information. Does anyone know if such dataset exists? If not are there known websites where I can scrape the information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSpOC - now 18th SPCS - uses following values:

- Payloads and platforms (5meters),
- rocketbodies and unknownobjects
  (3meters),
- debris(1meter)

The catagorisation of each object can be found in the NORAD-SAT-CAT, you can access via [Space Track](http://www.space-track.org)

Another database is [the ESA-Discos-DB](https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/), which bases on real dimensions and not a catagorisation. But you need to apply for an access!

A good page containing also dimensions of objects is [Gunter's space page](https://space.skyrocket.de/), but I do not think there is an automatic access...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the current standard calculations made using mentioned classifications?

Comment: @EgeElgun: There are no (largely accepted) "current standard calculations". But as far the calculations are concerned 18th SPCS is sharing, yes they use the classifications.

Comment: And yes: this results in putting 5m for every 10cm CubeSat

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan McDowels's *General Catalog of Artificial Space Objects* includes that information. See the object catalog at https://www.planet4589.org/space/gcat/web/cat/index.html
(download links in the menu on the left).

Specifically the *length* (longest dimension excluding antennas/solar arrays) and *span* (including everything) columns.